# Is there a way to send cross-domain requests by specifying you do not want to send any browser data?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, cross-domain

As far as I can see, it seems reasonable for a browser to allow sending requests to a different domain as long as there are no cookies being sent to that domain.

Cross-domain attacks as I understand would - if not for the protections in place - take advantage of the ajax request (I'm doing ajax) sending the browser's cookies to another domain, which would allow the script in the malicious domain to get access to possibly sensitive data.

Thus it would stand to reason that if you didn't send any cookies, it'd be essentially the same as sending a request from incognito mode where you're not logged into anything. I can't imagine it would introduce any possibility for exploitation aside from maybe if some website only used some ip-based verification, which in itself seems like it would be fairly idiotic and a use-case unlikely to be protected by the standard at such a high cost.

Thus, I feel like I'm missing something and there's a very obvious way to tell the browser "hey just get this image for me please, no need to send cookies or anything - you don't need to be logged in to access it anyway".

Is there? And if not, why?

Comment: You can always make these kinds of requests server-side. Make a request to your own local script which gets the image and returns it to you. In PHP for example, you can do this with cURL.

Comment: I am aware, but my goal was to make a small single-file "app" without having to even run a server in the first place - hence why it'd be useful to be able to do this.  
I'm also aware of the public "proxies" that would for this, but that's more clunky than I would like, and an extra point of failure.

Comment: Unclear what you are expecting as an answer here....

Comment: @epascarello A way to send a request to a different domain through telling the browser that I don't want to send any user data along with that request, as it seems like it would make sense for that to be possible. If it is not possible I would love to know the reasoning behind why it's not. In other words, something like an argument to ``XMLHttpRequest.open`` or ``fetch``.

Comment: Have you looked at using fetch?

Comment: @epascarello Maybe I'm just doing it wrong but a simple fetch request to a youtube video page yields a ``blocked by CORS policy`` error. I've tried with ``no-cors``, which just gives me a null body.

Comment: Well that error is saying they are not allowing you to make a request to their domain.... They did not set the header to allow the cross domain call.

Comment: @epascarello A 403 status code would be saying that. My error is the browser saying "hey you can't have this because it might be sensitive data from the other website (even though I did make the request and got a response)" - which makes no sense because I didn't send any cookies and thus there can be no sensitive data.
Either that or I did send cookies implicitly, which I did not intend - and if there is a way to not send them so as to have the browser then hand me the response, it would be great. And was my initial question to begin with.

Comment: @epascarello sorry did not see your edit, nevermind the 403 thing

Comment: You basically are disagreeing with the whole CORS policy. The browser knocks on the domain and says... hey can I come in.... they say no. Has nothing to do with what you are sending to them.

Comment: @epascarello Well if I'm disagreeing with it, I'm disagreeing with it in the sense that it doesn't make sense (from what I can tell) to keep from the script a response that would have no chance to contain sensitive data either way. There really is no point when I can just use a proxy which simply doesn't CORS-block me, I was just trying to figure out if there was a way in which I didn't have to go through the trouble as it seems sensible that there would be one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I can see, it seems reasonable for a browser to allow sending requests to a different domain as long as there are no cookies being sent to that domain.

Consider a company intranet which allows access to anyone on the same local network as the server.

> Thus, I feel like I'm missing something and there's a very obvious way to tell the browser "hey just get this image for me please, no need to send cookies or anything - you don't need to be logged in to access it anyway".

There isn't.

---

The Same Origin Policy takes a Secure By Default approach. It isn't loaded down with complex rules containing potentially exploitable exceptions.

Comment: Well I don't think the company analogy holds up, I can just use a CORS proxy, or if I had a server of my own use that. Would be analogous to everyone not being within the same network as the server but instead having public root SSH access to a machine that was. Really it's just extra steps. I do appreciate your outright telling me there isn't a way. Too bad though that security has to come down to "lock it all up" instead of putting responsibility on developers.

Comment: Neither your server nor the CORS proxy server would exist on the company LAN so neither could access the protected server. It isn’t extra steps. It is impossible. As for “putting responsibility on the developers” that would be wildly irresponsible, you can’t expect a hundred junior developers on a hundred projects (and juniors will be given this sort of responsibility) to handle complex systems with large collections of exception based rules. Security needs to be fundamental to system design, not left to the outside edge.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood. I thought you were making an analogy there. It all just clicked for me now. That makes a lot of sense, I only considered the case where the browser user could be the victim, not the case where another device in the network could be the target of the attack. I've just made a fool of myself then. Thank you!